# MariaDB: changing ENUM in a trigger raises exception

Tags: mysql, enums, triggers, mariadb

Assuming, I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Value` ENUM('VAL1','VAL2') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and the following trigger:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `test_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `test` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

SET NEW.`Value` := 'VAL1';

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now I can insert some rows, but if I use an invalid enum-type, I get an error:

`INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'VAL2'); // Statement ok, "Value" is set to 'VAL1'`

`INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'VAL5'); // Exception 'SQL Fehler (1265): Data truncated for column 'Value' at row 1'`

It seems, there is a check for valid ENUM values before the `INSERT`-Trigger fires.
Why is that? How can I establish a trigger to change invalid ENUMs to valid ones?

I saw a lot of examples, where this behaviour apparently do not occur. Can it be a misconfiguration? We use MariaDB 10.5.9.

Comment: Yes, datatype check is performed each time: before trigger, in the trigger, between triggers, after BEFORE triggers and before insertion. INSERT is independent of triggers, triggers are independent of each other. Parameters list must be correct in each point. And this cannot be altered. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9bc3a817997ff5d88c0241e151224a60

Comment: But what is with examples like https://joshuaotwell.com/mysql-triggers-for-data-integrity-in-lieu-of-check-constraints-part-2/ ?
By the way, dbfiddle.uk ... thank you for the link! ;-)

Comment: In the example ENUM value is compared with zero `0` - this is not ENUM list value but ENUM index value, and zero value means "was set to empty string". This is legal.

Comment: @Akina, Please post your answers as answers, not as comments. If you satisfy a user's question, they'll move on, and Stack Overflow will have a growing collection of "unanswered" questions.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. I think, ENUM = 0 means an invalid value, like described in the text, and not a empty string like '', which must be defined in the ENUM definition as another value.
And what sense makes the line `SET NEW.kind = 'other';` in the example trigger, if this value can not be inserted in the table?
To summarize, it's not possible to change ENUMs within triggers, if the valid values do not contain both OLD and NEW values?

Comment: *I think, ENUM = 0 means an invalid value, like described in the text* The only text you may refer to is Reference Manual. Read it at least now: [The ENUM Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html#enum-indexes). Zero value validity depends on Server SQL Mode - if STRICT_TRANS_TABLES is set then zero is not legal.

Answer (score 0):

Akina (see first comment) is right, it is not possible to change an unknown `ENUM` value even in a trigger.
The solution in my case was to include all possible values in the `ENUM`-list.  So the trigger can do it's work and change the 'forbidden' values to allowed ones. The only caveat is having now some `ENUM` values without any using in the data.